# How can I merge two partitions. One being primary C: and other being E:. One is in between. Recovery partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, ntfs

There are no one beside another. Program is not allowing me to merge them.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Disk Manager]

What is this 450mb Recovery? I had Xubuntu on new E: partition witch I formatted to NTFS.  Recovery partition witch 450mb only gives me 'Help' setting on right click. I don't know what to do. But I would like to merge C: and E:

Comment: One reason you are probably having troubles is because your "E:" is a logical partition inside an extended partition (as shown by the Green border/bars in the partitioning programs).

Comment: You'll have to move the recovery partition. It'll probably mean shrinking the partition E drive is in to make room at the end of the drive for recovery, then moving Recovery, then expanding C or E to fill the space between them, then merging. Frankly, because E is empty, you should just delete E, move Recovery, then expand C.

Comment: Now it's primary partition but still can't merge. What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Partitions cannot be "merged". You must copy any files that you may need from the E: drive into your C: drive, and then delete the E: partition.

The "Recovery" partition was likely installed on disk by the computer manufacturer, and is meant to provide a way to restore the machine to original factory condition, and/or to access special utilities to repair a booting problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Easeus tool you'd

- delete e: (assuming it's empty)
- move the recovery partition towards the end of the drive
- then extend c: into the free space between c: and the recovery partition.

If Easeus does not allow the recovery partition to be moved then that's end of story unless you decide you can do without it.